# How to reset the counter of a for loop in java

Tags: java, for-loop, counter, reset, joptionpane

So I am trying to create a program for my class in high school to be able to generate a random number and have a user keep guessing until they get it right.

So far I have everything going perfectly, except when I prompt them to play again, the counter that counts how many times they have guessed doesn't reset after they chose to play again. I don't know what to do for it, and searching for a solution, it was too complicated for me to understand or use.

Take note that this is only my second month of programming, so the code might seem amateur and I might seem terrible at programming. I just need a solution and perhaps an explanation.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import java.awt.*;

public class RandomNumberGuesser{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        UIManager m1=new UIManager();
        Color g = Color.gray;
        Color lg = g.brighter();
        m1.put("OptionPane.background", lg);
        m1.put("Panel.background", lg);

        for(x = 1; true; x++){
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.nextInt(100);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "This program will generate a random number from 0 to 100 which you have to guess.",
            "Number Guesser",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            String guess = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Guess a number.",
                "Guess",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                if(guess == null){
                    System.out.println("The user has terminated the program");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            int guess1 = Integer.parseInt(guess);

            if(guess1 > 100 || guess1 < 0)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Guess is out of range!\nPlease enter valid input.",
                    "Invalid Input",
                    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

            else if(randomNumber > guess1)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "You guessed too low.\nGuess again!",
                    "Your guess",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            else if(randomNumber < guess1)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "You guessed too high.\nGuess again!",
                    "Your guess",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            else if(randomNumber == guess1){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "You guessed the number right!\nIt took you "+x+" attempt(s) to guess it.",
                    "Congratulations!",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Want to play again?", "Play again?",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                   null, 
                   "Want to play again?", 
                   "Play again?",
                   JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
    System.exit(0);
} else {
    x = 1;
}
```

Just reset the counter to its initial value.

Note that you should avoid creating a new `Random` object every iteration. Create it once outside your loop and just call `random.nextInt(100)` every time.

Comment: So simple, yet a life saver. Thanks!

Comment: I think the "Not that ..." has to be "Note that ..." but I couldn't edit it since an edit must have six characters.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the loop before it start iterating just initialize your counter to the initial value before the counter started.
This ensures that in each loop the value of the counter is the initial position

```
counter=0;
```